# Looking for a 90s tv show (approx. 5 min per episode) about the special effects in Science Fiction movies

Tags: story-identification, tv, special-effects

I remember when I was a kid in Canada, there was a series of short episodes explaining how special effects were made in science fiction movies. I remember there was an episode on Armageddon and Flubber. I also, remember that the opening credits was the White House exploding from Independence Day.

Anyone remember the title of that show?

Comment: “the opening credits was the White House exploding from Independence Day” — take _that_, America!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was likely the Discovery Channel's *[Mega Movie Magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_Movie_Magic)* (or its predecessor *Movie Magic*).

As can be seen in the opening, it covers *Flubber* and does end with a shot of the White House being blown up from *Independence Day*

### Dubbed Opening

Not matching, the episodes are about 20 minutes in length, not 5.

Comment: It is not exactly how I remember it. Because I watched it in french, maybe the french adaptation was a little bit different to shorten it to 5 minutes. Thank you!